# Detecting VM Shutdown Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab to train models, but my models and data are large enough that I don't finish training before the VM shuts down. I know that I can checkpoint my model intermittently, but I'm looking for a way to detect when the VM is about to shut down so that I can save all my checkpoints and not waste any of the time I spent training. Is there a way to detect when the VM shuts down so I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no shutdown signal, so your best bet is to checkpoint periodically to a persistent file storage, e.g., [Drive](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA).